# Parsing date string to timezone not working when using zone id in Android?

Tags: android, date, timezone

I am trying to parse the following UTC string into a date in the central timezone.

`date = "2019-11-18T16:00:00.000Z"`

This code works and parses the date string into a date object with the timezone applied:

```
private fun getTimeZoneDate(date: String): Date {
    val parser = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
    parser.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST")
    return parser.parse(date)
}
```

However, I need to use the zone ID as it is what my API returns. This does not work:

```
private fun getTimeZoneDate(date: String): Date {
    val parser = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
    parser.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago")
    return parser.parse(date)
}
```

What is the different? Why doesn't the second chunk of code do anything to the string date but the first chunk (with timezone set to "CST") work?

Comment: Kindly add some more code, which is about passing data

Comment: Escaping "Z" AND using a different time zone offset than UTC+00:00 is an error.

Comment: I suspect that "CST" is not recognized as valid time zone so it is internally handled as falling back to UTC (what is by accident correct here).

Comment: @PJain Functions have been added.

Comment: @MenoHochschild this works for all values, not just that one. Using "CST" as a timezone properly converts the UTC date back by 6 hours. The "America/Chicago" code doesn't work and leaves it as UTC.

Comment: Please, look at my first comment. For parsing you have not to specify any other time zone offset than UTC+0 as long as you have an input ending with "Z", because that is the ISO-8601-notation for UTC+0. by definition. If you want to see the parsed result in another timezone then you have to format it using a separate formatter where you specify the time zone you need.